# How to toggle the display of element if date start equals date end

Tags: jquery

I want to make a condition if `txtDate == txtDateEND` and form for `selJam` will display as a `dropdown`. If txtDate not equal txtDateEnd and form for `selJam` will be hidden or will no display..  According to my code, I still fail to make selJam show or hidden.

```js
function checkDates() {
  var txtDate = $('#txtDate');
  var txtDateEnd = $('#txtDateEnd');
  var selJam = $('selJam');


  if (txtDate.val() == txtDateEnd.val()) {

    selJam.show();
  } else {
    selJam.hide();
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Date Start<input type="date" name="txtDate" id="txtDate" onchange="checkDates()" /> Date End<input type="date" name="txtDateEnd" id="txtDateEnd" onchange="checkDates()" />

</div>
</div>
<select id="selJam" name="selJam">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: You was close you need just  to add `#` to your selector like `$('#selJam')`

Comment: `$('#selJam').toggle(txtDate.val() == txtDateEnd.val())`

Answer (score 1):

1. You were missing the # on the selector
2. Try this instead - more elegant and recommended unobtrusive. Note how I removed the onchange and assign the event handler to the fields

```js
$(function() {
  $('[type=date]').on("change",function() {
    var txtDate = $('#txtDate');
    var txtDateEnd = $('#txtDateEnd');
    $("#selJam").toggle(txtDate.val() === txtDateEnd.val())
  }).change(); // initialise on load or use CSS to hide
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Date Start<input type="date" name="txtDate" id="txtDate"/> Date End<input type="date" name="txtDateEnd" id="txtDateEnd"  />

</div>
<div>
  <select id="selJam" name="selJam">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close you need just  to add `#` to your selector like `$('#selJam')`:

```
var selJam = $('#selJam');
```

But I suggest to avoid the use of inline-event `onchange` and to attach the `change` event in your JS part like :

**NOTE:** It will be better for your logic to hide the `selJam` element by default.

```js
$('#txtDate, #txtDateEnd').change(function() {
  var txtDate = $('#txtDate').val();
  var txtDateEnd = $('#txtDateEnd').val();
  var selJam = $('#selJam');

  if (txtDate == txtDateEnd) {
    selJam.show();
  } else {
    selJam.hide();
  }

  //OR
  //selJam.toggle(txtDate == txtDateEnd)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Date Start<input type="date" name="txtDate" id="txtDate" /> 
  Date End<input type="date" name="txtDateEnd" id="txtDateEnd" />
</div>
<select id="selJam" name="selJam" style="display: none">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```